# The rule S1144 for C# is wrong

Tags: c#, sonarqube, partial-classes

I think the rule S1144 is wrong for the C# partial class. Here is an example:

```
public partial class MyClass (CodeFile1.cs)
{
    private void DoSomething(object a, object b) { }
}

public partial class MyClass (CodeFile2.cs)
{
    public void DoSomethingElse()
    {
        DoSomething(a, b);
    }
}
```

In this case, SonarQube reports a bug saying "Unused private types or members should be removed" is not correct. I think it can't detect the using of DoSomething(a, b) in the same code file.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you tell us which version of SonarC# you are using? If this issue is raised using SonarLint for VS, could you tell us which version you are using and also whether you are using VS2015 or VS2017?

I made some tests with the latest version of SonarLint for VS2015 and I can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: We are using the SonarQube version 5.6.4 - LGPL v3 to analyze the code written in Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: @AmauryLevé: do you have any update on this?

Comment: You have given me the version of SonarQube you are using but not the version of the C# plugin (SonarC#) and/or the version of SonarLint for VS you are using. You are mentioning VS2013 for which we have no SonarLint so I guess you are talking about analysis with the Scanner for MSBuild?

Comment: You are right, I'm using SonarQube runner in TeamCity to analyse code written in VS2013, and it turns out the above issue. Please help me to check

Comment: Could you tell us which version of the C# plugin (SonarC#) you are using? The one installed on the SQ server.

Comment: It is 5.7.0.612

Comment: I just made a test using SonarLint for VS in connected mode to a SQ server using the version 5.7.0.612 of the plugin (with the rule enabled) and can't reproduce the FP you are mentioning.

Comment: Could you make a test by putting the 2 definitions of the partial class into the same file. Also could you provide the logs of the analysis of the project? I am guessing this has something to do with the fact you are using VS2013.

Comment: Upgraded SonarC# to 5.9.0.1001 and tried with the following code, I see there is no issue. So it's good. Thanks for your support.